# Does $\sum_{n=2}^\infty \frac{\ln(n)}{n (n - 1)}$ converge?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

> Does $\sum_{n=2}^\infty \frac{\ln(n)}{n (n - 1)}$ converge?

[Wolfram alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sum%20ln(n)%2F(n(n-1))%20from%202%20to%20infinity) suggests that the series converges. But I don't know yet how to prove it.

Attempting to apply the [root test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convergence_tests#Root_test) I got a complicated limit that I don't know how to evaluate:
$$
\limsup_{n\to\infty}\sqrt[n]{\left|\frac{\ln(n)}{n (n - 1)}\right|},\quad
a_n=\frac{\ln(n)}{n (n - 1)}.
$$

Attempting to apply the [ratio test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convergence_tests#Ratio_test) I got
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty}\left|\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_{n}}\right|=1,
$$ 
which means that the ratio test is inconclusive in this case.

Comment: It helps for these problems to remember that for any positive constant $a$, for all sufficiently large $n$, we have $\color{blue}{\ln n \le n^a}$. Then choose a value of $a>0$ that will help for the problem at hand, e.g. by letting us use the comparison test. For example, $a=1/2$ will help here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{\frac{\log n}{n(n-1)}}{\frac{\log n}{n^2}}=1,$$your series converges if and only if $\displaystyle\sum_{n=2}^\infty\frac{\log n}{n^2}$ converges. Which it does, by the integral test. Just use the fact that$$\int_2^\infty\frac{\log x}{x^2}\,\mathrm dx=\lim_{M\to\infty}-\frac1M-\frac{\log M}M+\frac12+\frac{\log2}2=\frac12+\frac{\log2}2.$$

Answer (score 4):

Yes, in this case the ratio test and the root test are inconclusive. 
My hint: show that, eventually,
$$\dfrac{\ln(n)}{n (n - 1)}\leq \frac{1}{n^{3/2}}.$$
What may we conclude?

P.S. We can replace the exponent $3/2$ with any real number in $(1,2)$.

Answer (score 1):

The actual value is in https://oeis.org/A131688
$$\sum_{n\ge 2} \frac{\log n}{n^2(1-1/n)} = \sum_{n\ge 2}\sum_{j\ge 0} \frac{\log n}{n^{2+j}} = -\sum_{j\ge 0}\zeta'(2+j)\approx  1.2577468869443$$
where $\zeta'$ is the first derivative of the Riemann zeta function.