# Is there a closed form solution to $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{\ln\left(\frac{n+1}{n}\right)}{n}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, definite-integrals, summation, logarithms, closed-form

While coming up with an idea for another way to milk the integral in [my previous question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4828799/ways-to-milk-the-integral-int1-0-ln-left-phix-phi-x-right-ln-l), I got stuck at this summation: $$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{\ln\left(\frac{n+1}{n}\right)}{n}$$

I do not know how to approach this summation and Wolfram Alpha does not give a closed form. It is approximately equal to $1.25771469823$. If it is any help, it is the solution to $\int_{0}^{1}\frac{1}{x\operatorname{floor}\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)}dx$.

Comment: [This post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3454128/evaluating-int-01-ln-left-lfloor-frac1x-right-rfloor-dx?noredirect=1) evaluates a similar named constant which does not have a known closed form

Answer (score 3):

Expanding the $\ln\left(1+\frac 1n\right)$ terms allows to rewrite your series as $\;\displaystyle \tag{1}S=\sum_{n=1}^\infty (-1)^{n+1}\frac {\zeta(n+1)}n$
(or $\;\displaystyle S=\log 2+\sum_{n=1}^\infty (-1)^{n+1}\frac {\zeta(n+1)-1}n$ for faster convergence)

We may too use the [generating function for $\zeta$](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/402988/21783) ($\psi$ is the digamma function)
$$\tag{2}\psi(1+x)=-\gamma-\sum_{n=1}^\infty \zeta(n+1)\;(-x)^n$$
to rewrite your sum as an integral :
$$\tag{3} S=\int_0^1 \frac{\psi(1+x)+\gamma}{x} dx$$

(I don't know a closed form but see [this thread](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1905761/prove-the-integral-int-01-frach-ttdt-sum-k-1-infty-frac-ln-1-f) or the paper [Series Involving Euler’s Eta (or Dirichlet Eta) Function](https://cs.uwaterloo.ca/journals/JIS/VOL24/Frontczak/front22.pdf) )

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4255279 :)

Comment: Yeah quite similar to my answer! Since them I discovered that $S$ could be obtained using the limit at $0$ of $\;\displaystyle f(x)=\frac 1x \sum_{n>1} \frac {n^x-1}{n(n-1)}\;$ with $f(-n)=-1+\frac 1n \sum_{k=1}^n \zeta(k+1)$. Cheers,

Comment: ... which I just noticed being also the starting point of your question... Gasp... :-) (I searched only the numerical value at the end and missed thus your thread!)

Comment: To close the loop your link at the end goes to an older [answer of mine](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/125663/21783) finishing with $S=-\sum_{k=2}^\infty \zeta'(k)$

Answer (score 3):

Since absolutely convergent by comparison to $\sum\frac 1{n^2}$

You can remove the telescopic part i.e. $\sum\left(\frac{\ln(n+1)}{(n+1)}-\frac{\ln(n)}{n}\right)$

To conserve $\sum\frac{\ln(n)}{n(n+1)}$ and apparently you can express this in term of $\zeta'$ see [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4180119/399263) but still an infinite sum...

See also this page on [Alladi-Grinstead Constant](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/Alladi-GrinsteadConstant.html)

Comment: +1 Interesting expression for the $\zeta'$ series! Cheers,